# How does the asker know what answer is correct?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, accepted-answer

Let's say I'm a beginner and ask a question which someone answers, should I just wait until theres a couple different answers which are voted around (or one voted highly)?

I've only used tech stackoverflow, where its usually obvious when something is correct/wrong, but maybe this is a solved issue on SE

Comment: Related MSE question: [How do I accept an answer when I have no expertise to know which is correct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99807/335251)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, based on my experience on English Language and Usage Stack Exchange, it isn't always true that the most upvoted answer is the correct answer. If you are not sure, you don't have to accept any answer. However, it would be nicer if you could research further into your answer and pick one as an accepted answer. It entirely depends on you.

Second, a correct answer tends to attract more upvotes while an incorrect one does downvotes. You can base your decidion on the number of upvotes.

Third, it is better to wait for a couple of days before accepting any answer. The community members are likely to comment if there is something wrong or unclear with an answer.

Once you submit your question or answer, it belongs to Korean Stack Exchange and it is no longer your property. That's why we need to make every effort to post well-researched and definitive questions and answers.

Answer (score 7):

The idea of stack exchange is that you can tell by upvotes - "Good answers are voted up and rise to the top", as [the tour page](https://korean.stackexchange.com/tour) says. Unfortunately, it doesn't always work! Often earlier answers get more votes than (possibly better) later answers, and sometimes someone will downvote a good answer, which may lead others to do the same!

The more people we get participating on the site (and on each question), the better the voting mechanism will work.

There may be two or more correct answers, approaching the question from a different perspective. I'd encourage you to upvote all helpful answers, and accept the one that's most helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that, if the questioner knows which answer is correct, they wouldn't have to ask the question in the first place.

On SE sites, acceptance is not intended to indicate correctness.  It indicates that the questioner finds it to be the most helpful answer of those available.  They may find an answer helpful even though a different answer is correct.  Equally, they may decide to accept none of the answers.

This is why the questioner may, at any time, remove acceptance from an answer and accept a later, better answer.

You will find around the SE sites any number of blatantly wrong but accepted answers.  That is just how it works.

Comment: *It indicates that the questioner finds it to be the most helpful answer of those available.* I disagree, if the answers are not correct, you don't have to chose one of them.

Comment: That is true.  You don't have to accept any of them - if none are particularly helpful to you.

Comment: @Yuriko I disagree. What if the questioner doesn't know whether it is correct or not? The questioner can find an incorrect answer helpful and choose it. If the questioner **thinks** the answer is correct, (s)he has every right to choose it and I think Chenmunka meant it. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

If you ask something, then you will have answers of different up voting numbers. So in my thought, you don't need to choose the best answer when it is not possible. I recommend that in this time you would consider **which answer is more helpful to you**.

When I answered in other site, my answer is accepted even though there is another more perfect answer with a lot of up votings.

And I recommend that you would have strategy when you ask. That is, you would point **exact point** where you do not know. If this is not possible, then you would ask a **reference** around your question.